# Ctools Modal on input change - not submitting

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, ajax

I am trying to load a modal popup when selecting an item in a select list. I can get the modal to launch with the new form inside but pressing save button does not do anything. Looking at the logs, all it says is invalid form POST data. It seems the issue is in `ajax_get_form()`.

This following function returning empty :

`$form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);`.

Anyone know what the issue is?

```
    /**
 * Form for creating rules.
 */
function audience_cohort_add_rule_form($form, &$form_state, Group $group) {
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();  

  $form['rulesets'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Rulesets'),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="data_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['rulesets']['rules'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Membership setting between every rule set'),
    '#description' => t('This setting determines how the audience rules will behave if you define more than one rule set. It is based on the logical "AND" and "OR" operators.'),
    '#options' => array(
      'and' => t('AND'),
      'or' => t('OR'),
    ),
  );

  if (!isset($form_state['num_new_items'])) {
    $form_state['num_new_items'] = 1;
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_new_items']; $i++) {
    $form['rulesets']['ruleset'][$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Set'),
    );

    $form['rulesets']['ruleset'][$i]['rules'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Membership setting between each rule in this rule set'),
      '#options' => array(
        'and' => t('AND'),
        'or' => t('OR'),
      ),
    );

    $form['rulesets']['ruleset'][$i]['addrule'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Membership setting between each rule in this rule set'),
      '#options' => array(
       'User Profile' => array(
          'user-idnumber' => 'ID number',
          'user-username' => 'Username',
          'user-email' => 'Email address',
        ),
      ),
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'audience_cohort_rule_add_form_ajax',
      ),
    );    
  }

  $form['rulesets']['add'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'add another ruleset',
    '#href' => '',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'audience_cohort_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'data_wrapper',
    ),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  );

  $group_roles = group_type_load($group->type)->getRoles(FALSE);
  foreach ($group_roles as &$group_role) {
    $group_role = $group_role->label();
  }

  $form['roles'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Roles'),
    '#description' => t('Select the roles the member will receive.'),
    '#options' => $group_roles,
    '#default_value' => array(),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save Rule'),
  );

  $form_state['num_new_items']++;

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
 *
 * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
 */
function audience_cohort_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['rulesets'];
}

/**
 * Select the modal form ajax callback
 */ 
function audience_cohort_rule_add_form_ajax($form, &$form_state) {

  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');                
  ctools_modal_add_js();

  $new_form_state = array(
    'ajax' => TRUE,
    'title' => t('Add rule'),
  );

  $new_form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $new_form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($form_state['triggering_element']['#value']);

  $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('audience_cohort_rule_add_form', $new_form_state);

  if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
    print ajax_render($commands);
    drupal_exit();
  } else {
    print ajax_render($output);
    drupal_exit();
  }

}

/**
 * The form that should be displayed in the modal
 */ 
function audience_cohort_rule_add_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['equal'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Operator',
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('contains'),
      1 => t('does not contain'),
      2 => t('is equal to'),
      3 => t('starts with'),
      4 => t('ends with'),
      5 => t('is empty'),
      5 => t('is not equal to'),
    ),
  );

  $form['listofvalues'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Value',
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;  
}

/**
 * Form submit function (never gets called)
 */
function audience_cohort_rule_add_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
}

/**
 * Validate handler for gadd_add_member_form().
 */
function audience_cohort_add_rule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
}

/**
 * Submit handler for gadd_add_member_form().
 */
function audience_cohort_add_rule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?